# C segmentation fault in array of strings

Tags: c

I expect the following code to work. It compiles (gcc), but the executions gives `Segmentation fault: 11`. How come? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INDEX_LENGTH 20

main()
{
    char **indici;
    int n = 4;

    indici = (char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        indici[i] = (char *)malloc(MAX_INDEX_LENGTH * sizeof(char*));
    }

    strncpy(indici[0], "aaa", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
    strncpy(indici[0], "bbbb", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
    strncpy(indici[0], "ccccc", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
    strncpy(indici[0], "ddddddd", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Index %d is %s\n", n, indici[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful answers have been posted yet, but I want to point out that you are allocating `MAX_INDEX_LENGTH * sizeof(char*)` instead of `MAX_INDEX_LENGTH * sizeof(char)` which is what you actually want I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying all of the strings into indici[0], so the other 3 are uninitialized.

When you print the uninitialized ones, *kaboom*.

Answer (score 2):

You're not populating all the elements, only `indici[0]` so they remain uninitialized and likely **point to garbage**. So when the second `for` runs it will dereference uninitialized stuff.

Maybe you meant:

```
strncpy(indici[0], "aaa", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
strncpy(indici[1], "bbbb", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
strncpy(indici[2], "ccccc", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
strncpy(indici[3], "ddddddd", MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
```

A second problem is that you're trying to print `indici[n]`, which is outside the allocated memory. You probably meant

```
printf("Index %d is %s\n", i, indici[i]);
```

---

Another subtler problem is this:

```
(char *)malloc(MAX_INDEX_LENGTH * sizeof(char*));
                                         ^^^^^^
```

You're allocating more than you need. You need to allocated a number of chars, so it should be `sizeof(char)`. But **`sizeof(char)` is always 1** so it should be:

```
malloc(MAX_INDEX_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Try to run this, it will crash too. OP has problem in last loop.